# Modal bootstrap - keyboard ipad adds blank space under modal backdrop

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I just can't figure out what is causing this problem. When i scroll down the modal window to the last input field and I click on it to bring up the iPad keyboard then it works like expected.

But if I don't scroll down (so that the bottom is partially hidden because the modal window is bigger than the height of the window) and i then click the input field, this is the result:

[image]

I have googled so many websites and possible fixes but nothing seems to work. i was able to get the backdrop to the bottom when this occured (just simple negative bottom) but the modal window itself still would not behave properly.

I use the default bootstrap v3 modal.

Comment: We redesigned the modal. We now have a fixed header and footer and the content scrolls between them. It seem to have fixed our problem. i don't seem to have that problem anymore but maybe an update fixed it..

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
.modal-open {
  min-height: 100% !important;
}
```

To your stylesheet.